# Not getting all the record of username from json in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, intellij-idea, android-listview

Hello everyone i am parsing a json file in which i am just fetching fields data "username"  and "email" but i am not getting all values from the both fields instead i am getting only 5 values from the json file of "username" and "email" fields.

```
 body: new Center(
       child: new ListView.builder(itemCount: _quakes.length,
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.8),
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context , int position)
           {
             if(position.isOdd ) return new Divider();
             int index = position ~/ 2;
             return new ListTile(
              title: new Text("${_quakes[index]['username']}"
              , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 19.2),),
               subtitle: new Text("${_quakes[index]['email']}",
               style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.9),),

             );


           }
      )
    )
```

Comment: Based on your code, you can only get half of `_quakes.length` because return divider in odd index. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: i want to get all values not half so what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a separator, You can use [`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html) :

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: _quakes.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return new ListTile(
              title: new Text("${_quakes[index]['username']}"
              , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 19.2),),
               subtitle: new Text("${_quakes[index]['email']}",
               style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.9),),

             );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider();
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your condition you have to do your itemCount * 2. it will work..